# themable jquery UI dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking for a jQuery dropdown that can be themed using jQuery UI.
There existed some examples at http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html but these are not supported now in jQuery UI 1.8

Is there something else I can readily use or do I need to create my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The autocomplete widget has an example that uses what they call a combobox, which is essentially a themed drop down.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

You should be able to take the source provided and modify it to work with a normal `<select>`.

Answer (score 9):

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) come to mind

Comment: Thanks. The libraries look good but they are rather bulky (50KB) for just a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

It seems selectmenu is supported at least now in 1.11.4

https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/